# How to set values to a field

Tags: apex, trigger

I've a class.which I assume that set a value to field.But it is not assigning any value.Can anyone help me.

```
public class SampleTriggerClass {
     public static void SampleMethod1()
     {
     SampleAddObj__c SAO=new SampleAddObj__c();
     SAO.SampleAddress__c='Hyderabad';
     }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your visualforce page code also.

Comment: You should describe your problem as specifically as possible. Start with words, not code. And at a high level. What are you trying to achieve? Which portions of your code are relevant?

Comment: I've a custom object (SampleAddObj__c) and a custom field(SampleAddress__c) in it, and a class (SampleTriggerClass).I would like to send a value from class to field.

Comment: Are you trying to update something or insert the record so the field `SampleAddress__c` reads "Hyderabad"? Is `SampleMethod1()` called by a Before Trigger?

Comment: Yes..Here is my trigger

Comment: trigger duplicateEmployee on SampleTrigger__c (after insert) {

SampleTriggerClass.sampleMethod1();
}

Answer (score 2):

So to clear things up, you have the following Trigger:

```
trigger duplicateEmployee on SampleTrigger__c (after insert) {
  SampleTriggerClass.sampleMethod1();
}
```

With the following class:

```
public class SampleTriggerClass {
  public static void SampleMethod1() {
    SampleAddObj__c SAO=new SampleAddObj__c();
    SAO.SampleAddress__c='Hyderabad';
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but the reason you're not getting a new record added to your `SampleAddObj__c` object is because you're not performing any DML on the object you've created in your code.

In which case you'd just need to add `INSERT SAO;` to your code under `SAO.SampleAddress__c='Hyderabad';`

So:

```
public class SampleTriggerClass {
  public static void SampleMethod1() {
    SampleAddObj__c SAO=new SampleAddObj__c();
    SAO.SampleAddress__c='Hyderabad';

    INSERT SAO;
  }
}
```

What this will do is whenever you add a new `SampleTrigger__c` record, it will create a new `SampleAddObj__c` record and assign the value: "Hyderabad" to the field `SampleAddress__c`.

This isn't all that useful, but it is why you're not seeing any new records.